# Is there any way to Block a sql query in python?

Tags: python, mysql

I am making a full python software which will be used to perform sql queries but i want to block some the the queries like DROP DATABASE so that no one can execute it via my python program

i want that no one can use this statement to DROP things is SQL

```
mycursor.execute(DROP DATABASE 'database name here')
mydb.commit()
```

or

```
sql="DROP DATABASE 'database name here'"
mycursor.execute(sql)
mydb.commit()

#I WANT NO ONE CAN USE THIS QUERY
```

Comment: Yeah, write the logic yourself. maybe `if 'DROP DATABASE' in user_query: break; else: cur.execute(user_query)` or etc

Comment: Also this is a very bad idea. Don't allow users to write arbitrary SQL queries in your application.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this [list of SQL injection attacks](https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/sql-injection-cheat-sheet/#SyntaxBasicAttacks) and maybe that will discourage you from trying to write your own logic for this.

Comment: Nowadays databases are mostly used by trusted agents like web applications which operate with elevated permissions on behalf of the users. But earlier they have actually been designed for connection from multiple authenticated users with different credentials and permissions.  Maybe you want to pick up that "old" style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be done with database permissions if at all. Alternatively, you could try to parse the SQL and determine whether to allow the query.

However, this seems like a bad idea. Untrusted input should almost certainly not be passed as a database query.

Comment: 1+ for pointing out database permissions - that’s a very important point.